# Wrong date save when send to server

Tags: actionscript-3, date, apache-flex

I have datefield in my flex application.

When i set one date and send to server as remote service call. It will save wrong depend on timezone.

Like suppose as per my current timezone it's 12th Apr and i set date 13th Apr in function parameter. Then it will set date 12th Apr not 13th Apr.

```
<mx:DateField id="dtNewDate" selectedDate="{new Date()}" change="dtChangeHandler(event,data)" />
```

I have send it's selected value as parameter. I debug and check it will send proper selected date(13th Apr).

[image]

function is Java. I have tried many things but, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use BlazeDS or something simular. Actually it's a feature (a bug) that `Date` is serialized and passed to Java as timestamp, not the local DateTime.

You have several solutions:

1. Use custom `Date` or `DateTime` class that extends `Externalizable` inteface.
2. Use custom class that contains primitive fields year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds
3. User custom serialization mechanizm
4. Add local time offset to AS3 `Date` in setter methods and subtract that offset in getter methods. But that way is full of drawbacks.

Comment: How to use custom date class? And it is work when i send that to function as parameter?

Comment: Replace AS3 `Date` with your `CustomDate` at model (domain) classes. For interoperability with `DateFiled` you should add methods `toDate()` and `fromDate()` to `CustomDate`.